What is rational integral function?
I am doing problems in $\textbf{Demidovich}$'s Problems in Mathematical Analysis, and the 8th question in Section 1 is:


Find the rational integral function $f(x)$ of degree $2$ if $f(0) = 1, f(1) = 0, f(3)=5$.


I guess it wants me to find the quadratic function which satisfies the condition, but I am wondering why the quadratic function here is also called $\textbf{rational integral function}$. Here the coefficients of this quadratic function are rational, but the function and this question have nothing to do with "integral" in mathematical sense.
So can somebody help explain what "rational integral function" is with some example, and how this name was developed historically? Thanks!

I think you may have posted this on the wrong site as I am unclear what the historical question is here. Can you edit to clarify?

It means polynomial. The phrase I'm more familiar with is "integral rational function" (see my list of 1800s math terms here), but it seems "rational integral function" is also relatively common in older literature. In fact, without looking into this (which I don't have the desire to do so now), I'm not sure which is the more common phrase, although to me "integral rational function" seems to be a better word ordering (via a "integral rational-function" reading).

@mdewey Sorry, my bad! Have edited it.
